# Research work on computational models for a "specific" person's behaviors

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, simulation, pattern-recognition, agent-based-computing

Is there active research work on creating computational models of a "specific" person's behaviors (general behaviors, emotions, actions...)? What are some references for such research? I tried google and scopus and did not have much luck.

I have worked on modeling movement behaviors of pedestrians in crowd (for my PhD work), but I am planning to work on the simulation of general behaviors of individuals (based on the historical data of their actions and behaviors).

I am more inclined to use machine learning methods than detailed mathematical models.

Comment: Way outside my area of expertise, but perhaps the following book touches on the topic: C. Breazeal, Designing Sociable Robots, MIT Press. 2002.  There are chapters about "Motivation" and "Behavior", but I don't know if they're relevant.

Comment: Might be of interest to you: https://gravityandlevity.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/pedestrians-as-interacting-particles/.  For the general question, you could look in the HCI community (e.g., the CHI conference), where many researchers have studied using machine learning to try to predict aspects of people's behaviors, attitudes, emotional state, etc.  Surveying all of that work is beyond the scope of an answer on this kind of site.  The techniques used tend to be specific to the kind of thing you want to predict, but have included Hidden Markov Models, standard ML algorithms, and more.

Answer (score 1):

this is a broad area now overlapping with [big data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) and ([mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_surveillance)) [surveillance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance) technology. here are a few refs with scientific elements/ angles/ leads/ papers/ books etc. and reference to a new field of ["social physics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographic_gravitation)

- [‘Social Physics’ Harnesses Big Data to Predict Human Behavior](http://www.datanami.com/2014/05/21/social-physics-harnesses-big-data-predict-human-behavior/) / Leopold
- ['Big data' reveals human interests, behavior](http://phys.org/news/2014-03-big-reveals-human-behavior.html) / Kullman, physorg
- [What Can Big Data Ever Tell Us About Human Behavior?](http://www.forbes.com/sites/martinzwilling/2015/03/24/what-can-big-data-ever-tell-us-about-human-behavior/) / Zwilling, Forbes